# Flutter how to get onResum for ios

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, onresume

How to catch app open new page and come back 
from google i got a lot of answer and nothing solved my issue
some of them are

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => {
      print("SchedulerBinding")
    });
```

and

```
SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg){
      debugPrint('SystemChannels> $msg');
      if(msg==AppLifecycleState.resumed.toString())setState((){});
    });
```

and

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(
        LifecycleEventHandler(resumeCallBack: () async => setState(() {
          print("yes_resumeCallBack");
          // do something
          mBloc = NotificationBloc(context);
          //mBloc.start();
          mBloc.loadTodo();
          //mBloc.getAllVisitNotificationFromApi(startLimit: 1, endLimit: 1);
        }))
    );
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final AsyncCallback resumeCallBack;
  final AsyncCallback suspendingCallBack;

  LifecycleEventHandler({
    this.resumeCallBack,
    this.suspendingCallBack,
  });

  @override
  Future<Null> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    print("state");
    switch (state) {

      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        if (resumeCallBack != null) {
          await resumeCallBack();
        }
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        if (suspendingCallBack != null) {
          await suspendingCallBack();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```